# how to remove my chat's extra characters? C++

Tags: c++, sockets

This my chat mixed with threads to run server and chat at same time. The problem is when I send a message to the chat lets say "Hello" as the first message,
and "bye" as the second 
Output will go:
Hello
Byelo And some extra characters that I do not want there
how to remove my chat's extra characters and letters? C++
I tried    cout<<"Message: "<

### But it did not seem to work

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cpl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID);
HANDLE Thread_Handle = NULL;
DWORD Thread_ID      = 0;

DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID data)
{

    while(1){        
    WSADATA t_wsa; // WSADATA structure
    WORD wVers; // version number
    int iError; // error number

    wVers = MAKEWORD(2, 2); // Set the version number to 2.2
    iError = WSAStartup(wVers, &t_wsa); // Start the WSADATA


if(iError != NO_ERROR || iError == 1){
    //  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Error at WSAStartup()", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();

    }

    if(LOBYTE(t_wsa.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(t_wsa.wVersion) != 2){
   // MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Error at WSAStartup()", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();

    }

    SOCKET sServer;
    sServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if(sServer == INVALID_SOCKET || iError == 1){
    //  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Invalid Socket!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();

    }


    SOCKADDR_IN sinServer;
    memset(&sinServer, 0, sizeof(sinServer));

    sinServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sinServer.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // Where to start server?
    sinServer.sin_port = htons( 1002); // Port



    if(bind(sServer, (LPSOCKADDR)&sinServer, sizeof(sinServer)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        /* failed at starting server */
    //  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not bind the server!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();

    }
    while(listen(sServer, 20) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    Sleep(10);

}



  SOCKET sClient;
    int szlength;

    szlength = sizeof(sinServer);
    sClient = accept(sServer, (LPSOCKADDR)&sinServer, &szlength);
    if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET){
    //  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not accept this client!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
    closesocket(sServer);
        WSACleanup();
    } else {
   // MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Accepted a Client!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Success", MB_OK);
  }
  // Now we can send/recv data!

    int iRet;
    char buffer[200];
//  strcpy(buffer, "Welcome to our Server!\0");
    iRet = send(sClient, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); 
    if(iRet == SOCKET_ERROR){
        //MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not send data!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        closesocket(sClient);
    closesocket(sServer);
        WSACleanup();

    }
    char autoresponse[80];
    int bytes;
//  strcpy(autoresponse, "Message Received!");
    autoresponse[strlen(autoresponse)-1] = 0;
    //MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Server is ready for messages and is hiding!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Success", MB_OK);
    char *cClientMessage;
    cClientMessage = new char[600];
    cClientMessage[599] = 0;
  while(bytes = recv(sClient, cClientMessage, 599, 0)){

    if(bytes < 1){

      continue;
    }
char cRead[99];///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



     cout<<"Message: "<<cClientMessage<<"       \n";     




      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        iRet = send(sClient, autoresponse, strlen(autoresponse), 0); 
        if(iRet == SOCKET_ERROR){
        //  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not send response!", (LPCTSTR)"Server::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
      }}

  delete [] cClientMessage;
    // Cleanup
    closesocket(sClient);
    closesocket(sServer);
    // Shutdown Winsock
    WSACleanup();


Sleep(10);
}
    return (0);
}

int main()
{
    Thread_Handle = CreateThread(NULL,0,Thread,(LPVOID)0,0,&Thread_ID);


    while(1){

char IP[100];
char message[255];
cout<<"IP: \n";
cin>>IP;                    

char buffer[150];
    WSADATA t_wsa; // WSADATA structure
    WORD wVers; // version number
    int iError; // error number

    wVers = MAKEWORD(2, 2); // Set the version number to 2.2
    iError = WSAStartup(wVers, &t_wsa); // Start the WSADATA

    if(iError != NO_ERROR || iError == 1){
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Error at WSAStartup()", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    /* Correct version? */
    if(LOBYTE(t_wsa.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(t_wsa.wVersion) != 2){
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Error at WSAStartup()", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKET sClient;
    sClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if(sClient == INVALID_SOCKET || iError == 1){
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Invalid Socket!", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN sinClient;
    memset(&sinClient, 0, sizeof(sinClient));

 char cIP[50];

    sinClient.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sinClient.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP); // Where to start server?
    sinClient.sin_port = htons(1003); // Port

    if(connect(sClient, (LPSOCKADDR)&sinClient, sizeof(sinClient)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        /* failed at starting server */
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not connect to the server!", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }

    while(1){            
cout<<"Message: \n";
cin.getline(message,255);
string input2 = message;  

    // Now we can send/recv data!
    int iRet;
    char cBuffer[600];
    char buffer2[260];


//  MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Connected!", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Server", MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);

    strcpy(buffer, message );



iRet = send(sClient, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); //send data 




    if(iRet == SOCKET_ERROR){
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Could not send data!", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
}

    int bytes;
    bytes = SOCKET_ERROR;
    char *cServerMessage;
    cServerMessage = new char[600];
  while(bytes = recv(sClient, cServerMessage, 599, 0)){
    if(bytes == SOCKET_ERROR){
        char cError[500];
            sprintf(cError, "Connection failed, WINSOCK error code: %d", WSAGetLastError());
            MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)cError, (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            closesocket(sClient);
        // Shutdown Winsock
        WSACleanup();
      return 0;
    }
    if (bytes == 0 || bytes == WSAECONNRESET) {
      MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)"Connection Disconnected!", (LPCTSTR)"Client::Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
      closesocket(sClient);
      // Shutdown Winsock
      WSACleanup();
      return 0;
    }
    if(bytes < 1){
      Sleep(300);
      continue;
    }   
    delete [] cServerMessage;
    // Cleanup
    closesocket(sClient);
    // Shutdown Winsock
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;


}
Sleep(10);
// This is how to terminate a thread // TerminateThread(Thread_Handle,0);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can format the code you enter in your question with 4 spaces.  It will make it much more readable and you'll probably get better answers.

Comment: edited code part. Needs more work though.

Comment: Seems to me you're missing a null character somewhere

Comment: Yes but the question is where???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recv()` doesn't append a `'\0'` to the end of the bytes written. You need to use the return value of `recv()` and add the `'\0'` yourself.

Comment: Where would i add that never messed with this before new to sockets

Comment: right after `recv()` so after `bytes = recv(sClient, cClientMessage, 599, 0)` you could do something like `cClientMessage[bytes] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the extra byte of bandwidth, the quickest fix is probably just to send strlen(buffer)+1 bytes insead of strlen(buffer) bytes in your call to send().

Comment: Just added a new character before the message
"Hello=.2

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place first 4 bytes to be the length of the message?

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple (I don't think performance or style are a concern here), you should probably memset the entire cClientMessage (eg. memset(cClientMessage, 0, 600)) in the function Thread.  Then also do the same from the sender with message in main.

You are getting stale characters from the previous message since the \0 is not being transmitted or set by the receiver.